# Equation number on wrong line

Tags: equations, numbering

Hi my equations produce their numbers on the following line as opposed to the same line.
Here's an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}$$ $I_{3}^{-}(sol) \longleftrightarrow I_{2}(sol)+I^{-}(sol)...  Dissociation$ $$ \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: *Don't* use `$$`...`$$` or any other math escaping `$`...`$` inside `equation`. So just use `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`.

Comment: `\begin{equation}$$ $ ... $ $$\end{equation}` is too much of a good thing, do you want `\begin{align} blah \end{align}`. If you ware interested in TeX for chemistry try [`mhchem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mhchem) or [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros).

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap Can you supply an answer?

Comment: @egreg: done (and old comment removed for cleanup).

Answer (score 1):

(By request, here's my comment posted as an answer. You should be on the lookout for a specialised chemistry package to typeset such equations in a clear and consistent way — the advice in this answer is generic to displayed math in general.)

You only need to use a displayed math environment such as `equation` or `gather`, if you want to display a single equation. Also, you should put explanatory text (such as `Dissociation` inside the argument of a `\text` command; and labels which are part of the equation (such as `(sol)` for your ions) should be put inside the argument of a command such as `\mathrm`.

**Example.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
     I_{3}^{-}\textrm{(sol)}
  \longleftrightarrow
     I_{2}\textrm{(sol)}+I^{-}\textrm{(sol)}
  \qquad
     \text{\ldots Dissociation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample chemical formula]

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{equation}
I_{3}^{-}(sol) \longleftrightarrow I_{2}(sol)+I^{-}(sol)...  Dissociation
\end{equation}
```

Like that

clean
pretty
awesome

Comment: Not very clean, though, when you consider that "Dissociation" is not meant to represent the product of variables `D`, `i`, `s`, `s` again, `o`, `c`, `i`, `a`, `t`, another `i`, `o` again, and `n`.

Comment: @NieldeBeaudrap, You are talking about the content of the equation, I am talking about placing the equation in the same line of the number. This creates the needed effect. I undestand that the code would be better if it explained the content but alas sometimes we just want a specific format. I think you should post your answer as an answer. It gives the pretty effect and the representation you say... it is more correct.

Comment: True, you do solve the original problem. But it's always a good idea to suggest an answer which doesn't contain any other errors of formatting. I'm refraining from posting an answer because I don't want it to distract from or reduce the chances of a forthcoming answer which is even better. (Sorry if my earlier remark was a bit snide.)

Comment: Oh no need to apologize. I thank you for your comment. I think the formatting from your code looks prettier in the end product. This makes it all worthwhile, it is... a better answer, and not only that, it is simple, without adding any further packages.